# Entity framework Core Condition for Column insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
     protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "BoolMe_Filtered_Index",
            table: "Records",
            column: "Records",
            filter: "([Property1]=(1),([Property2]=(1),([Property3]=(1))");
    }
```

I need to create a condition where  the property BoolMe cannot be true unless the 3 properties are true as well.

This gives me incorrect syntax on ",".

How to achieve this?

Or Better yet

I'm not sure if the way i did is the correct one with index. Even if it's wrong i don't know how else i can solve this with EF Core

Comment: Looks like you are seeking for check constraint functionality which is not currently supported out of the box by EF Core.

Comment: ah so that's what i need a check constraint, I figured indexing was not the way to do this. Is there any other way to achieve this in EF Core or I have to do it code wise?

Comment: check filter value, brackets ( are not balanced